# Unable to connect to Oracle 11g on virtual machine via JDBC: Connection reset

Tags: java, linux, oracle, jdbc, vmware

I have Windows 7 installed on my laptop which has VMware Workstation with Oracle Linux 5.5. There is Oracle 11g r2 database on Linux and I need to estabilish the connection via JDBC from host(Win7) to database on guest system(Linux) using NAT. So then I run this java code on Windows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Connection con;
    try{
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.68.0.1:1521:orcl", "system","oracle");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I get this exception:

```
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: I/O Exception: Connection reset
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:428)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:536)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:228)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
    at OracleTest.main(OracleTest.java:15)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:196)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
    at oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive(Packet.java:283)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:287)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1054)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:308)
    ... 12 more
```

On Windows I assigned IPv4-address 172.68.0.1 to VMware Network Adapter VMnet8. Here is the picture with my  settings for Virtual Network Editor in VMWare and network configurations on Linux:

http://i.cubeupload.com/vAen5q.jpg

On Linux I also have:

listener.ora:

```
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 172.68.0.1)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = /u01/app/oracle
```

tnsnames.ora:

```
ORCL =    
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 172.68.0.1)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )
```

So I need to find out what's the problem and how to solve it. Please, help.

Comment: You're using NAT, change the guest configuration in VMWare to use [bridged networking](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws4/doc/network_bridged_ws.html). You could also try the [port-forwarding option(s)](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_net_nat_advanced.html).

Answer (score 0):

It's late, but I found a solution for this.

1. In Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager you have to go to Global Tools then you create a new adapter
2. Automatically it gives an IPv4 Address, with that address you can connect, but first you have to change the setting of your virtual machine,
3. Select your VM, for example Windows 10, then press Settings, now to Network, then in Attached to you have to select Host-only Adapter, in name you select the adapter that you created, then you press Ok.
4. Run your virtual machine.
5. In Java you can use this:

   connection.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@IPv4Address:1521:xe");

   connection.setUser("example");

   connection.setPassword("pass");

When you complete the all the steps you can connect from your host to the Database in your virtual machine.